# How to change the color of a diagram cell while hovering?

Tags: hover, jointjs

I have an uml diagram and I want to change the color of one cell when the cursor is on it.

I tried to do it programmatically, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```js
paper.on('cell:mouseover', function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
    var cell = graph.getCell(cellView.model.id)

    if (cell.isElement()) {
         cellView.model.attr({'uml-class-name-rect': { fill: '#33C3FF' }});
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can try to use the highlighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
paper.on('cell:mouseenter', function(cellView) { 
      var cell = graph.getCell(cellView.model.id);

      if (cell.isElement()) {
        cellView.model.attr({'.uml-class-name-rect': { 'fill': '#33C3FF' }});
      }
    });
```

CSS of class 'uml-class-name-rect' can't be set simultaneously through a global css file.